# Problem with Count Statement for Multiple Databases

Tags: sql

**Sorry everyone.  It appears that I am a dumbass!  The query works fine when I run it against the live database versus my test database...gotta pay more attention to that stuff!**

I am having a problem with the statement shown below.  It works fine if I run it against one database (sans the DBCATALOG.dbo), so no problem there.  When I try running the statement as is, I get an incorrect syntax  near ‘<’. 
I also tried using a tool to create a union for all of our databases (see second statement).  This results in an invalid object name error (Invalid object name 'TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03.dbo.LinkedDocumentFolderTable', Invalid object name 'TF7-TestDatabase-ScheduledRestore.dbo.LinkedDocumentFolderTable', etc.).
It seems to be tied to the .[dbo], but I just don’t know what causes the problem.  I can’t find anything in the book stating a count can’t be performed across multiple databases….

```
SELECT CNT=COUNT(*)
FROM <DBCATALOG>.[dbo].[LinkedDocumentFolderTable]
WHERE IsUnmanagedFolder = 1


SELECT 'TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03' AS DBCatalog, * FROM(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03].[dbo].[LinkedDocumentFolderTable]
WHERE IsUnmanagedFolder = 1)rsOne

UNION ALL

SELECT 'TF7-TestDatabase-ScheduledRestore' AS DBCatalog, * FROM(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [TF7-TestDatabase-ScheduledRestore].[dbo].[LinkedDocumentFolderTable]
WHERE IsUnmanagedFolder = 1)rsOne
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be weird. Try next:

```
SELECT 'TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03' AS DBCatalog, COUNT(*) 
FROM [TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03].[dbo].[LinkedDocumentFolderTable] 
WHERE IsUnmanagedFolder = 1
```

Also do you have all neccessary permissions set?
(I'd better not ask, do you have such databases like TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03 on same server present at all?)

Comment: Still getting an error... Invalid object name 'TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03.dbo.LinkedDocumentFolderTable'.

Comment: Yes, all the databases are held on our downtown server.  I am using Query Analyzer to run the query.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Otherwise I cannot understand your accept :)
What if you skip .dbo. part, using only db and table name [TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03]..[LinkedDocumentFolderTable] ?
Does sp_databases show that database at all? Maybe it is not loaded or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're actually trying to do, but those angle (< >) and square ([ ]) brackets aren't valid to have in the queries.

Which database engine are you using?

Comment: I am working in SQL 2005 (I think), SQL Query Analyzer Version SQL 8.00.760.  I am trying to perform a count across 100 databases using the <DBCATALOG>.[dbo] to call each database.

Comment: This is the error I receive if I eliminate the <> and []....Invalid object name 'DBCATALOG.dbo.LinkedDocumentFolderTable'.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted identifier for SQL Server is the brackets as you are using elsewhere ("[" and "]"), not the "<" and ">", so my guess is that's why you're getting the first error.

Are the databases actually named TF7-User-Demo-ScheduledRestore-03, etc.?

Also, when selecting from a subquery you need to make sure that all of the columns in the subquery are aliased if they don't already have a column name. For example:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS my_count)
```

Comment: Some of them are.  Our nomenclature is customername-location.  In the case above, this is a demo database for our company.